# Voice Recognition to Shiny App

Tags: javascript, r, input, shiny, voice-recognition

**Background** - I am trying feed voice based inputs to change selections in Shiny app. I am using the Annyang speech recognition library. There are applications demonstrating the input using "renderPlot" function in Shiny - https://yihui.shinyapps.io/voice/. Is there a way to feed it to other inputs like text fields and selectInput functions?

I am not familiar with JS either. Any help to achieve this would be much appreciated.

Ex: `

```
    library(shiny)

    shinyApp(
      ui = fluidPage(

    singleton(tags$head(
      tags$script(src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/annyang/1.4.0/annyang.min.js"),
      includeScript('C://init.js')
    )),

    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    title = "TSAP",


    div(id = "header",
        h3("TSAP"),
        tags$img(src="cl.png")
                    ),

    fluidRow(
      column(6,
             div(
               id = "form",

               selectInput("Name", "Name", 
                           choices = list("A", "B", "C") 

               ),
               actionButton("submit", "Submit", class = "btn-primary"),

               shinyjs::hidden(
                 span(id = "submit_msg", "Submitting..."),
                 div(id = "error",
                     div(br(), tags$b("Error: "), span(id = "error_msg"))
                 )
               )
             ),

             shinyjs::hidden(
               div(
                 id = "thankyou_msg",
                 h3("Thanks, your response was submitted successfully!"),
                 actionLink("submit_another", "Submit another response")
               )
             )
      )


       )
      ),

      server = function(input, output, session) 
        {

          output$Name = reactive({
            #col = input$color


#if (length(col) == 0 || !(col %in% colors())) col = 'gray'
        #plot(cars, main = input$title, col = col, cex = input$bigger, pch = 19)
        #lm_line()
        input$Name
      })



    }

)
`
```

init.JS

```js
var initVoice = function() {
if (annyang) {
  var bigger = 1;
  Shiny.onInputChange('title', 'say title something');
  Shiny.onInputChange('color', 'black');
  Shiny.onInputChange('bigger', 1);
  Shiny.onInputChange('yes', 'no');
  var commands = {
    'title *title': function(title) {
      Shiny.onInputChange('title', title);
    },
    'color :color': function(color) {
      Shiny.onInputChange('color', color);
    },
    'Execute': function() {
      Shiny.onInputChange('Execute', Execute);
    },
    'bigger': function() {
      bigger += 1;
      Shiny.onInputChange('bigger', bigger);
    },
    'smaller': function() {
      if (bigger >= 1.5) {
        bigger -= 1;
        Shiny.onInputChange('bigger', bigger);
      }
    },
    'regression': function() {
      Shiny.onInputChange('yes', Math.random());
    }
  };
  annyang.addCommands(commands);
  annyang.start();
  }
};

$(function() {
  setTimeout(initVoice, 10);
});
```

includeScript('C://init.js')
    )),

Is there a way to apply the function to feed input. Will reactive() serve as a solution and how to combine js to supply this information to Shiny?

Thanks

Comment: The best way to implement this is to create a proper [shiny input binding](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/building-inputs.html) based on the `.js` file and then use `updateTextInput` to channel the voice input to the text input.